# How to combine event registration fee and sponsorship donation in one price set?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, price-sets

I want to have a price set for an event which offers two mutually exclusive options: (1) registration fee for the event (2) a sponsorship fee. Option 1 should register the person as an attendee. Option 2 should not. In other words, the visitor either registers for an event, or makes a donation.

I thought that by putting 0 (zero) into the 'participant count' field for the second option, that it would not increment the participant count for someone who pays the sponsorship fee. But it DOES register the person for the event when all they are doing is making a donation. Am I missing something or can Civi not handle this use case without programming?

Answer (score 0):

The participant count is only participants for the particular price set field. You're right that no matter what you do in the price set, the contact will be registered for the event. You could instead ignore who is registered for the event and just look at who is registered for the relevant price set field and use that as your group of registered participants. That might be less than ideal.

Otherwise, this sounds like a job for Webform CiviCRM, assuming you're on Drupal. Be warned though, that Webform CiviCRM will force you to use line items to record the donation and registration. I could be wrong, but I don't think Webform will allow you to record two different financial types depending on user selections.

Comment: if you use WP then Caldera forms could probably do this.

Comment: You are correct about you cannot have 2 different financial types. You can use Webform for an event registration and a donation. But both will have the same financial type. Which is likely a problem for you when you try to create tax deductible receipts since the event fee is likely not tax-deductible but the donation is.

Comment: The tax receipt will work fine, no reason you can't have one tax deductible line item and one non-tax deductible line item. But it basically puts you in a position of having to use line items for everything, because the contribution financial type will no longer be reliable.

Comment: "But both will have the same financial type". I am not sure this is a true statement. webform allows you to set Line Items with different Financial Types now. wish i could add a screenshot to a comment. it is possible.

Comment: That was my experience when combining an Event Fee and Donation. But maybe I am confusing it with the Contribution Financial Type which would just be one entry for both parts. And that did cause problems for our year-end receipts.